# How to save and Update one column when another is changed

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a database column of type text that stores a hash in my database.

```
column_a = {sample_list: [{email: test@gmail.com},{email: test2@gmail.com}]}
```

I want to generate another column in the database that contains contains a string of email_address eg:

```
column_B = "test@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com"
```

I know how to get generate the string from the hash, my questions are what model changes do I have to make so that whenever `column_A` is populated, `column_B` should be updated?

How do I handle migrations of historic data in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassName < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :maybe_update_column_b

  def maybe_update_column_b
    update_column_b if column_a_changed?
  end

  def update_column_b
    #your code to update column b
  end
end
```

then (at a time you determine to be safe to do an update) run this in a console.  Find each will batch the data.

```
ClassName.find_each  do |cn| 
  cn.update_column_b
  cn.save
end
```

Comment: I'd go with this option, but Steven should use something like: `self.comlumn_b = ...` so that the same database commit saves both columns.

Comment: thats why I used a `before_save` call. I don't know what code he is using to update the `column_b`, but I would assume it would do `self.column_b=` not a direct db call.  and any changes made in a `before_save` call get persisted in the save.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I just mentioned that so that he's aware of it ;-).